# Cannot create group in openfire via SMACK API

Tags: smack

Unfortunately I am not able to create a group in openfire 3.8.2 via the SMACK API (3.2.1).

Here is what I am desperately trying to do:

```
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
RosterGroup group = roster.createGroup("FancyName");
roster.createEntry(connection.getUser(), "nickname", new String[] { group.getName() });
RosterEntry user = roster.getEntry("user@domain");
group.addEntry(user);
```

And that's it.
Afterwards there is no group in openfire.
What do I do wrong?

With thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tested your code with the application I'm developing and it creates the group + adding the users.

The problem with your code is that the group that you are creating is specific to each user roster, and will not be appearing in Openfire's *Groups* tab.

From what I've experienced with Smack/Openfire, the **shared roster groups** (those that you want to see in Openfire) cannot be created from the client side using Smack API.

Comment: Also, adding/removing/changing users to this type of groups can only be made using Openfire